# KDE equivalent of GNOME shell extension Caffeine

Tags: gnome, kde

Does anyone know if KDE has an equivalent of the [Caffeine](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/) GNOME shell extension? This extension will disable the screen saver and auto-suspend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Caffeine, try opening **Energy Saving** (either through the Application Launcher or in the System Settings), and untick **Suspend Session**

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/caffeine-ng/caffeine-ng

> caffeine-ng works with the following screensavers / screenlockers:
>
> - Anything that implements the org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver API (**this includes KDE**, amongst others)
> - [..]